# How to use both custom membership and single sign on on Azure

Tags: c#, facebook, azure, authentication, single-sign-on

I want to let my users to have access to my private services using both my custom membership data and a single sign on provider like Facebook. In [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-dotnet-service-principal-auth#next-steps) they've described how to let Azure use a SSO and how to prevent anonymos access. But then how can I combine the SSO part with my custom membership provider? (for example a name/password stored in microsoft membership DB)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Azure B2C:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/

Which can store your custom membership information, and also supports 3rd party authentication like `Facebook` and `Linkedin`.

Moving data from your current membership provider can be done with the `GraphAPI`